# linux: how to configure OOM killer to react sooner than 30 minutes after system freezes?

Tags: linux, out-of-memory

My Linux Mint often freezes when PC runs out of memory. I wonder why it takes ~ 30 minutes to unfreeze.

Today I want to do something about it. `dmesg` after unfreezing gave:

```
...
[Jan17 00:23] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 17
[  +0.000237] rndis_host 2-2:1.0 usb0: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:14.0-2, RNDIS device
[Jan17 00:53] INFO: task systemd:1 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[  +0.000008]       Tainted: P           O      5.15.0-41-generic #44-Ubuntu
[  +0.000002] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[  +0.000002] task:systemd         state:D stack:    0 pid:    1 ppid:     0 flags:0x00004002
[  +0.000005] Call Trace:
...
```

This PC gets internet via USB and was opening "heavy" web pages. I disconnected USB when PC started to freeze (line 1st?). Exactly after 30 minutes "systemd:1 blocked for more than 120 seconds", nothing before that. Any way to investigate further? Any settings to change to make the system react sooner? N.B. swap disabled.

P.S. There is a ton of related links on the web, I suspect some are relevant, however several I encountered first had not answered the question fully.

Comment: Try https://github.com/rfjakob/earlyoom

Comment: Rathet than messing with the OOM-KILLER (a pseudo-task, hard-coded in the kernel), consider adding swap space. With swap, your system will continue to run. 
Read `man mkswap fallocate  filefrag swapon fstab`

Comment: @waltinator, if the system has free memory for swap. Sometimes it has not.